# Converting existing Stripe customers to Stripe Connect

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I have a stripe account hooked up to my production app with over 200 stripe Customers with credit card information. I want to be able to have my customers "split the charge" (like Uber) with other customers which I believe is only a feature with Stripe Connected Accounts. Is there any way to transfer all of my Customers to Connected Accounts.

Also, I'd like to have these connected accounts be "managed" meaning that each user can't access their  stripe account as a standalone user. Would I really need all of the account info like date of birth and SSN? Unless that information gets entered and Connected Account shows up as pending.

Comment: by split the charge do you mean 2 customers pay for a single purchase?

Comment: @MatthewArkin Yes. So, using Lyft or Uber as an example, if the ride costs $20. The customer has the option to split the bill with another user and them each pay $10 (sometimes there is a small transaction fee).  I know this is possible [using Stripe Connect](https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-a-charge-s-funds-be-split-among-different-connected-accounts) , but there's no reference for how to change all existing customers to Strip Connect Accounts.

Comment: That is not possible for Stripe Connect. Stripe Connect lets 1 charge get split between Lyft and the Driver. You would just create 2 separate charges.